# java.net.ConnectionException: failed to connect to / 10.38.11.73

Tags: java, android, eclipse, tcp

I´m trying to connect andriod application with a server that I created. The server is running in Eclipse and I run the app in my device from Eclipse.

In my device, I have this error:

> java.net.ConnectionException: failed to conect to / 10.38.11.xx (port:5541): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

Both, the server and the device are connected at the same WIFI and the WIFI is running under proxy.

The connection is implemented by Sockets using TCP/IP protocol.

The app code is:

```
package com.example.localcli;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
   private static final String[] A = { "n/d", "preciso", "impreciso" };
   private static final String[] P = { "n/d", "bajo", "medio","alto" };
   private static final String[] E = { "fuera de servicio",
                                               "temporalmente no disponible ","disponible" };
   private LocationManager manejador;
   private TextView salida;

   private String proveedor;

   private String dato_localizacion;

   Socket sk;
   BufferedReader entrada;
   PrintWriter out;
   String ip = "10.38.11.73";
   int puerto = 5541;
   boolean conectado;



   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      salida = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);


      manejador = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
      log("Proveedores de localización: \n ");
      Conectar();
      muestraProveedores();

      Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
      proveedor = manejador.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
      log("Mejor proveedor: " + proveedor + "\n");
      log("Comenzamos con la última localización conocida:");
      Location localizacion = manejador.getLastKnownLocation(proveedor);
      muestraLocaliz(localizacion); 

      Desconectar();


   }

// Métodos del ciclo de vida de la actividad
   @Override    protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         // Activamos notificaciones de localización
         manejador.requestLocationUpdates(proveedor, 10000, 1, this);
   }

   @Override    protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         // Desactivamos notificaciones para ahorrar batería
         manejador.removeUpdates(this);
   }

//Métodos de la interfaz LocationListener
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          log("Nueva localización: ");
         muestraLocaliz(location);
   }

   public void onProviderDisabled(String proveedor) {
         log("Proveedor deshabilitado: " + proveedor + "\n");
   }

   public void onProviderEnabled(String proveedor) {
         log("Proveedor habilitado: " + proveedor + "\n");
   }

   public void onStatusChanged(String proveedor, int estado,
         Bundle extras) {
         log("Cambia estado proveedor: " + proveedor + ", estado="
                       + E[Math.max(0,estado)] + ", extras=" + extras +"\n");
   }

//Métodos para mostrar información
   private void log(String cadena) {
         salida.append(cadena + "\n");
   }

   private void muestraLocaliz(Location localizacion) {
         if (localizacion == null)
                log("Localización desconocida\n");
         else
                log(localizacion.toString() + "\n");
   }

   private void muestraProveedores() {
         List<String> proveedores = manejador.getAllProviders();
         for (String proveedor : proveedores) {
             dato_localizacion = stringProveedor(proveedor);
             enviarDato(dato_localizacion);
             log(dato_localizacion); 
         }
         enviarDato("#FIN#");
   }

  // private void muestraProveedor(String proveedor) {
    //     log(stringProveedor(proveedor));
   //}

   private String stringProveedor(String proveedor) {
       LocationProvider info = manejador.getProvider(proveedor);
       String datos_muestra;
       datos_muestra = ("LocationProvider[ "+"\n getName=" + info.getName()+
              ", \n isProviderEnabled=" + 
                                               manejador.isProviderEnabled(proveedor)+ 
              ", \n getAccuracy=" + A[Math.max(0, info.getAccuracy())]+
              ", \n getPowerRequirement=" +
                                                P[Math.max(0, info.getPowerRequirement())]+
              ", \n hasMonetaryCost=" + info.hasMonetaryCost()+
              ", \n requiresCell=" + info.requiresCell()+
              ", \n requiresNetwork=" + info.requiresNetwork()+
              ", \n requiresSatellite=" + info.requiresSatellite()+
              ", \n supportsAltitude=" + info.supportsAltitude()+
              ", \n supportsBearing=" + info.supportsBearing()+
              ", \n supportsSpeed=" + info.supportsSpeed()+" ]\n");

       return datos_muestra;
 }


   public void Conectar() {
       try {
         //Creamos el socket
           sk = new Socket (ip,puerto);

            //Comprobamos que ha conectado correctamente
            if (sk.isConnected() == true) {
                //Inicializamos el buffer de entrada
                entrada = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
                //Inicializamos el buffer de salida
                out = new PrintWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(sk.getOutputStream()),true);
                //Indicamos que esta conectado
                conectado = true;

                //Recibimos mensaje
                recibirDatos();

            } else {
                //Indicamos que no esta conectado
                conectado = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Si hubo algun error mostramos error
            log(" !!! ERROR  !!! "+ e.toString());
            Log.e("Error connect()", "" + e);
            conectado = false;
        }
   }

   public void Desconectar(){
       try{

               sk.close();
       }
       catch (Exception e) {}

   }

   public void recibirDatos() {
       try{
           //Datos de entrada
           String dato_entrada = entrada.readLine();
           //Mientras que el dato que nos envia el servidor sea distinto del
            //comando #FIN# (que nos indica que no hay mas datos a recibir), 
            //mostramos el dato leido y leemos el siguiente
            log("recibiendo ... "); 
            while (!(dato_entrada.equals("#FIN#"))) {
                log(dato_entrada);
                dato_entrada = entrada.readLine();  
            }

            //Al salir del bucle es que ha terminado la transmision de datos
            //log("Recibidos todos los datos");
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           log("Error al recibir los datos del servidor "+ e.toString());
       }

   }

   public void enviarDato(String datos_out) {
       if(conectado) {
           try {
               //Enviar dato
               out.println(datos_out);
               //Indicamos el fin de la emision con el comando #FIN#
              // out.println("#FIN#");
           }
           catch (Exception e) {
               log("Error al enviar los datos " + e.toString());
           }
       }
   }

}
```

I suppose the problem is with proxy server but I dont know how to solve it.
Thanks you in advance for your help and I´m sorry if my English is not well understood.

Comment: Most likely the problem isn't with your code but with something in your network-configuration...

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `http://10.38.11.xx/`. Also, make sure that it's actually up online just in case.

Comment: You don't specify the protocol while opening a socket. And I'm not sure he wants to speak http over the connection

Comment: The protocol used is TCP/IP and I don´t kwon if I can use http in this case